Linked Lists with Variable Length String Data
I'm writing a function that creates a linked list of string data for results returned from an SQL query made with ODBC. I know that the columns and rows it returns might be of random length so I'm trying to find the best way to go abouts calculating just enough memory to hold that column or row (max row length is 8KB!) and avoid using arrays.
I've currently built a function that adds the returned string value from an SQL query, and it is as follows.
// Structure to hold columns and rows
typedef struct node {
    SQLCHAR* data;
    struct node* next;
} node;

void AppendData(node** root, SQLCHAR* name) {
    node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (newNode == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory! Exiting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Allocate memory to store n width data
    newNode->data = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
    strcpy(newNode->data, name);
    newNode->next = NULL;
    // Create root node if no root exists
    if (*root == NULL) {
        *root = newNode;
        return;
    }
    // Loop until end of linked list is found and insert data
    node* temp = *root;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = newNode;
}

However, when I allocate a new node at the first line of AppendData function, would I not override that allocation if my string data is say, of 1024 bytes or something like that? Because I need to calculate the string length dynamically with strlen I believe this would cause an overflow?
How do I go abouts calculating just enough space and not overriding the linked list node?

It looks OK to me. You are not overwriting anything except the link pointer at the end of the list.

You have two (relevant) pointers, newNode and newNode->data. Because you call malloc twice, the two pointers will point to different memory.

Ah yes of course! Too early in the morning here, that slipped out of my mind. Thank you.

That code looks fine. The allocation for the node itself and node->data are two different allocations. Just make sure you free both when you're done with them in reverse order, so data first then node.


However, when I allocate a new node at the first line of AppendData function, would I not override that allocation if my string data is say, of 1024 bytes or something like that?

No. Your struct node is exactly the size of two pointers: one that points to a string which you allocate separately and one that points to another node. What you are doing here looks absolutely fine, with the possible exception that you test for a NULL newNode but not for a NULL newNode->data.
Note that, if your system supports strdup() (not guaranteed: it's POSIX rather than the C standard) you can just write
    newNode->data = strdup(name);

Note also that when you come to free a node you must first free node->data because it was allocated separately. For example:
// Assumes you have already taken aNode out of the list
void freeNode(struct node* aNode)
{
    if (aNode != NULL)
    {
        free(aNode->data);
        free(aNode);
    }
}

